# How to authenticate multi server URLs Using one Azue Application credentials

Tags: azure, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am using this package [php-crm-toolkit](https://github.com/AlexaCRM/php-crm-toolkit) to allow my clients authenticate with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Using Username, Password ( authentication Using Username and Password is deprecated now ) and use their Server URLs ,

Now to do the same you must register application in azure portal and authenticate using ( App ID, Secret ID ) it's more secure but this way is not clear and a little confusing for our clients to do.

1- So How can I make One Azure Application for my company and authenticate any Server Url for any client and use his data, is that doable ?

if not:

2- Is there a way to make it easier for clients like registering Azure application for them and get their credentials by using endpoint for example? OR Is there any service that allows me to authenticate for them using one credentials (mine).

Now I can just create one azure application and get my credentials and authenticate using them and use my server URL.

I want to have like a service or something makes me authenticate for any client in easy way without force him to open azure and create an application and get it's credentials.

Comment: the reply inside the issue you opened inside the repo doesn't satisfy your question?

Comment: @GuidoPreite 
It does and what I need is doable, but the article the author mentioned is a little confusing for me.
and there is no much resources in this i guess and I never implement something like that before.